# Not able to read json data using Spark

Tags: json, hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe, databricks

I am trying to read the `Json` data by using `Apache Spark`. Here is the code what i have tried so far:

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setAppName("ExplodeDemo")
      .setMaster("local")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
    val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._
val df = sqlContext.read.json("file location")
df.printSchema()
```

which works well when i pass the file name as a argument to the `sqlContext.read.json`, but my requirement is to pass the `json String` directly insted of file.

for that i tried i tried like this:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(r))
val df = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
df.printSchema()
```

where `r` is my json String, by using this code, there are no compilation errors. But when i tried df.printSchema() it shows like this, and not able to retreive the data.

```
root
 |-- _corrupt_record: string (nullable = true)
```

Comment: How does your JSON data look like? Spark can only read one JSON object per line (or per file if you set `multiline` to `true`)

Comment: It's a valid json, i do tested with jsonlint.com

Comment: i am not asking how to access sub entities of nested json, i am asking how its printing _corrupt_record insted of schema?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to provide schema as well.

DataFrame is just an RDD with Schema. While using Datasoure API, Spark will infer the schema by reading the file. As you are not using Datasoure APi to infer the schema automatically, you need to pass the schema explicitly.

```
val YOURSCHEMA= StructType(Array(
  StructField("Attribute1", LongType, true),
  StructField("Attribute2", IntType, true)))
val df=spark.read.schema(YOURSCHEMA).json(rdd)
df.printSchema
```